# How do I make python's inbuilt http.sever proxy a wsgi request

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, uwsgi

My app https://github.com/Leo-G/Flask-Scaffold, uses angularjs/html for the frontend and flask for the backend. I use nginx and uwsgi to serve them. However I wanted to know if there was any python module I can use to serve them both for development/testing/demo purposes only, I know I can serve the html with http.server but for any flask/wsgi request how do I tell http.server to proxy it to uwsgi or flask's inbuilt server running on another port?

Comment: Just run the application server with `app.run` or `flask run` (depending on if you are on 0.10.x or DEV)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used send_file_from(dir, filename) a flask inbuilt function to solve this issue. You can view my project for it's implementation https://github.com/Leo-G/Flask-Scaffold